# How do I make a background image responsive using css?

Tags: html, css

I placed an image as a header background-image for the body and wanted to make it responsive...However when i change the window size , the background is responsive however the image seems to clip somewhere and the actual image that needs to be in the focus disappears...

Here is the code:

```css
.topnav {
  background-image: url(/images/pastry-topnav-bgd-img.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="topnav"></div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Can someone help me with how i can make the image responsive in such a way that the background-image stays in focus and does not displace much

Comment: background-position: center center

Comment: Don't use `background-size: 100%` as it can skew the image. As mentioned above `background-position: centre` would help you keep it in the centre. But it can also keep the image focused on a particular area if u know its position. For example like this: `background-position: 20% 30%`.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to use this

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

instead of using

```
background-size: cover
```